# GPGGA doesn't show time

Tags: gps, nmea

As seen in:
http://aprs.gids.nl/nmea/#gga

The first part of the GPGGA sentence , is UTC time.  for example:

```
$GPGGA,123519,4807.038,N,01131.000,E,1,08,0.9,545.4,M,46.9,M,,*47
```

The UTC time is:    12:35:19

My GPS device output the sentence:

```
GPGGA,000019.032,,,,,0,00,,,M,0.0,M,,0000*5F
```

As I see it, this is a standard - these sentences have a certain structure. 
Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that your GPS does not have a fix yet.  If it doesn't have information from satellites, then it doesn't know what time it is.

The time you see is likely indicating that your GPS has been on for 19 seconds, or that it thinks it is 00:00:19 based on an internal clock that was running since the time was last received.

Comment: are you sure its the time? what does '032' in '000019.032' refer to? thanks

Comment: Fractional time.  19.032 seconds.

Comment: Thanks @Brad. Do you know where I can read more about it, because in the first example, it doesnt show fractional time.

Comment: @kakush, The first field is time.  NMEA is comma-separated.  Your GPS hasn't broken any rules.  Different units have different capability, and sometimes this minor differences show up.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like GPS is not in sync with satellite signal, so it is showing time from internal clock.

@kaushik, did you connected the antenna. If you connected pls check whether your gps has active receiver or passive receiver.

Comment: Hello. Since you are actually querying the OP whether or not he has attached the Antenna, I have to say If you are not posting an answer then don't use the answer submission utility. Queries are to be made in comments. But your rep is insufficient to do that so it is understandable.